# WPF - Changing the background of specific Controls within a child ItemsControl using MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism, styling

I have a three level hierarchy of controls: `ChordFinder` -> `PianoKeyboard` -> `PianoKey`.  The `PianoKeyboard` is an `ItemsControl` which contains specific logic to organize many `PianoKey`s into a keyboard layout.  Each `PianoKey` has an `IsHighlighted` property which, when set, in the default style changes the background color of the control to indigo.

The problem is, in the context of the `ChordFinder` there is the concept of a Root Note (the root of the possible chords) and to denote this I would like to highlight the root note's `PianoKey` in orange instead of indigo.  I understand I will have to assign the `PianoKey` in question a different style in order to do this but since each control is separated using Prism and (I assume) can only pass data to its children through the `RegionManager.RegionContext` I'm not sure how to tell certain `PianoKey`s that they need to use a special style defined in the `ChordFinder` rather than the default one defined in `PianoKey` without breaking MVVM and having style name data included in the View Model.

To give you an idea of the issue I'm dealing with here are some mock versions of my classes.

**ChordFinder**

```
<UserControl  x:Class="Music.ChordFinder.View.ChordFinderView"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
              xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
              mc:Ignorable="d"          
              xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"                                  
              xmlns:wpfInfrastructure="clr-namespace:Global.Wpf.Infrastructure;assembly=Global.Wpf.Infrastructure"
              d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>      
        <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static wpfInfrastructure:RegionNames.pianoKeyboardRegion}"
                        prism:RegionManager.RegionContext="{Binding PianoKeyboard}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**PianoKeyboard**

```
<ItemsControl x:Class="Music.Wpf.PianoKeyboard.View.PianoKeyboardView"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
              xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
              xmlns:converters="http://schemas.mycodebase.com/converters"
              xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
              xmlns:wpfInfrastructure="clr-namespace:Global.Wpf.Infrastructure;assembly=Global.Wpf.Infrastructure">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <converters:KeysToColumnsCountConverter x:Key="keysToColumnsCountConverter"/>
        <converters:KeysToRowsCountConverter x:Key="keysToRowsCountConverter"/>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<!--UniformGrid logic for keyboard layout omitted for brevity-->
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Grid.RowSpan="{Binding Note.IsSharp, Mode=OneTime, Converter={StaticResource isSharpToRowSpanConverter}}">
                <!--Grid placement logic omitted for brevity-->
                <prism:RegionManager.RegionName>
<!--This is logic to generate the appropriate region name to reference each PianoKey (e.g. "pianoKeyD4Region" for the key for the note D in the 4th octave)-->
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource formatStringToStringConverter}">
                        <Binding Source="{x:Static wpfInfrastructure:RegionNames.pianoKeyRegionFormatString}"/>
                        <Binding Path="NoteName" Converter="{StaticResource stringToCamelCaseStringConverter}"/>
                        <Binding Path="Octave" Converter="{StaticResource enumFieldToEnumFieldNumberConverter}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </prism:RegionManager.RegionName>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**PianoKey**

```
<Button x:Class="Music.Wpf.PianoKey.View.PianoKeyView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:converters="http://schemas.mycodebase.com/converters">
    <Button.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="keyStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsHighlighted}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Indigo"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </DataTrigger>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="naturalKeyStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource keyStyle}">
<!--Style ommitted for brevity-->
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="sharpKeyStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource keyStyle}">
<!--Style ommitted for brevity-->
        </Style>
    </Button.Resources>
    <Button.Style>
        <Binding Path="IsSharp" Converter="{StaticResource isSharpToKeyStyleNameConverter}"/>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

What's the best way to change the background color of the `PianoKey` I want to make highlighted a different color based on logic in the `ChordFinder`?

Comment: *"I understand I will have to assign the PianoKey in question a different style in order to do this"* oh good heavens, no. Just give it an IsRootNote bool property and put a trigger in the style to set the background to a given brush when that property is true. Put it after the IsHighlighted trigger so it'll override that one.

Comment: I'm trying to keep the separation of concerns present though - in the context of a `PianoKeyboard` there is no such thing as a 'Root Note' but there is in my Chord Finder.  I guess I could abstract the name with something like `IsAlternativelyHighlighted` but then suppose another control needs a further highlighting extension - do I call that `IsAlternativelyAlternativelyHighlighted`?

Comment: As a musician and a programmer of many decades, I implore you not to try to abstract root notes out of music. No viewmodel has to use them. Beware creating real programming problems in an effort to forestall phantom pattern-purity problems! That's a great evil.

Comment: But an alternative is to have "note roles" or something. Each note has a "role", which is an `int?`. Have default brushes for each role, and parent view can set different ones. Role `null` is plain key color. Parent VM gives each note a role value. VM has no business knowing what colors are used.

Comment: Just to elaborate `IsHighlighted` is used elsewhere in a `ScaleFinder` so that when a key is pressed then released, the `IsHighlighted` property inverts to indicate that that key is or is not selected as one of the keys that must appear in the available scale (thinking about that, `IsSelected` would have been a better name for both that and the ChordFinder).  `Role` would be less clear but then more extensible for multiple states albeit limited to internal style support.

Comment: I just wanted to take advantage of WPF's lookless control concept here as it seemed appropriate to do so since I can't think where else an `IsRootNote` property on the `PianoKey` would be used.  I'm using this project as a learning exercise of how to do MVVM properly as my experience in WPF has been more on the vein of tightly-coupled Views and View Models with code-behind for the View Model.

Comment: IsHighlighted doesn't sound like a role to me -- tonic is a role, major third is a role. It's the major third whether it's being played at the moment or not. Again, beware trying to generalize everything to death. You can really make a mess that way.

Comment: It sounds like a very cool exercise.

Comment: Now that you've mentioned diatonics or intervals as roles it actually makes a lot of sense!  I'll keep `IsHighlighted` (maybe change it to `IsSelected`) and add the `Role` property to `PianoKey` as I can document that with something meaningful now.  I've heard from a few sources that WPF can be problematic when it comes to wanting to restyle only part of a template so I guess adding bespoke roles to the style won't be possible without restyling the entire `PianoKey` - I guess 12 roles ought to cover most scenarios for a normal Piano Keyboard - I'm not supporting 22-note octave pianos yet!

Comment: One thing you can and probably should do is give your keyboard a default key Style, but let consumers provide a style via a dependency property, much like `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle`. They can derive it from the implicit style via `Style.BasedOn`. So a consumer could override certain existing triggers, for example. But yeah templates are basically used as-is, or replaced.

Comment: Thinking about the `Role` property again it still seems like a bit of a magic number property.  I've limited its value using an `OrdinalClassification` enum I created for values from "Primary" (1st) to "Duodenary" (12th) but the fact that whatever it's being used for might not need all of those values makes me think it's more loosely-typed than it should be.  It still beats copying and pasting my whole `PianoKey` style templates for every control I need to add a new DataTrigger to the `PianoKey` for.  I'm just wondering whether I could style the ItemContainer for each key as the key instead...